# Is there an easy way to download entire folders from the Dropbox website?

Tags: dropbox

I occasionally need to get files from my Dropbox account when I'm using a computer not under my control. I can download or access individual files on the dropbox website, but is there a convienent way to download entire folders, preferably in some sort of archive?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is pretty easy.  Simply check the check box next to the folder(s) you want to download and then go to

More Actions > Download Folder

You can also do this to download multiple files within a folder.  Check all the items you want to download and then go to

More Actions > Download Items

Comment: With the new UI you can click the top file/folder and shift click the bottom file/folder then press the download button.

Comment: This answer was originally posted in 2010. It no longer applies to the current version of Dropbox.

Answer (score 10):

The above mentioned solutions do not work anymore.

Instead, open the folder you want to download and click to select individual files, or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to select all files. A row of buttons will appear above the list of files, click the *Download* button to download the selected files as a Zip compressed archive.

EDIT:
[Matthew Crumley's solution](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/687/is-there-an-easy-way-to-download-entire-folders-from-the-dropbox-website/773#773) works as well, just be sure not to click the folder name itself, as it will open the folder instead of selecting it. The *Download* button will appear in the row of buttons above the folder list, and not in a drop-down menu as mentioned.

Comment: Can back that up with a reference?

Comment: I guess a [screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/VyyYD.png) of the functionality in question should do.

Comment: You can also produce the dropdown menu by _right_-clicking the folder in question, like [so](http://i.imgur.com/b967E.png).

Comment: this is helpful - I found this as I was actually looking for way to copy folders from one part of dropbox to another (for sharing purposes) - sadly, although "Copy" is an option on your right-click screenshot, it isn't there any more (at least for my shared folders)

Comment: Note: "above" really has no context here. Answers can sorted in numerous ways.

Comment: It seems there is something broken currently in Dropbox. When I try this method browser just downloads file named `unspecified` with contents `<html><script>history.back();</script></html>`.

Comment: It appears this [unspecified dropbox](https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/Installation-and-desktop-app/Why-do-I-only-get-the-file-that-is-called-quot-Unspecified-quot/td-p/163777) [error](https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/Error-messages/Error-downloading-folder-through-web-client/td-p/163205) is over a year old and still not resolved. ( In my case it helped to narrow downloaded folders size from 280 Mb to 125 Mb.

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to download a single folder, you can just click to the right of the folder you want to download (in the blue highlight box around the folder), and choose "Download Folder" from the drop-down list.

Comment: What if a friend shared a folder with me and I want to download it. Yet Dropbox says it is too big and I need to save it in my Dropbox. Yet I don't have account and don't want to create. Is there application which automates it?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to download folders all at once. I work for a law firm and We had a HUGE document production to download.  25 folders on the main page with subfolders inside. I was VERY glad I discovered this method.  It took minutes to do as compared to saving each document individually. The above options did not work for me so if they didn't work for you either, try this.

Go to the opening screen for your project in Dropbox and click on the "DOWNLOAD" button, then RIGHT click on "Download as .zip" option and choose "Save Target as".  This will permit you to navigate to your hard drive to save the zip file where you desire.

To open the zip file, again right click and choose "Open With" then "WINZIP" (if that is your extraction program of choice) and another screen will open so you can then extract the files.

Comment: What if a friend shared a folder with me and I want to download it. Yet Dropbox says it is too big and I need to save it in my Dropbox. Yet I don't have account and don't want to create. Is there application which automates it?

Answer (score 0):

Dropbox has changed quite a bit since this question was asked in 2010, so here's a more up-to-date answer.

---

**Click the `...` button to the left of your folder, then click `Download` in the newly opened window. You'll then be prompted to save the entire folder as a `.zip` file.**

[image: Downloading folder from Dropbox]

Comment: Not up to date anymore.